# Are elements searchable in a multimap? Is it needed?

Tags: c++, containers

If I have Key->Elements

```
A->B,C,D,E
```

Are B,C,D,E searchable , i.e. are they inserted into a red and black tree.

I think the answer is no.  I think I would need a

```
multimap<string,map>
```

to make the value part searchable efficiently (i.e. part of a red and black tree)

```
A->B,C,D
B->C,D
C->D
D->E
```

If I use a map of sets, this would best describe this structure.  Each Key of the map points to a set.  Each set is basically a list of Elements.  Because I'd like efficient searching and inserting I'm using std::map and std::set instead of std::list and std::list.

Comment: Leaning toward a map of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value part to be a sequence with efficient look-up time, you can use

```
multimap<string, set>
```

if the elements of the value-sequence are unique, or

```
multimap<string, multiset>
```

if not. This would give you logarithmic lookup time, and logarithmic insertion (this can be better or worse depending on the type of insertion, look at `std::set` and `std::multiset` documentation). The sets behave much like the `std::maps`, except that the value of each element is its key.

Comment: So sets use a binary tree similar to maps

Comment: Yes, self-balancing binary trees, but the details are up to the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

No -- neither map nor multimap will do that. You'd want something like a [Boost bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/index.html) for this.

Comment: Can I just use a map of sets?

Answer (score 1):

> I think I would need a `multimap<string,map>` to make the value part searchable efficiently (i.e. part of a red and black tree)

You think right.

> But if they keys and values are in oder then do I need an associative container at all. Wouldn't it be better to use a vector?

If they're in order, and you don't plan on adding or removing elements quickly, then yes - a binary search (provided in `<algorithm>`) in a `vector` can be expected to outperform a `map` lookup.